# Perl "else" statement not executing

Tags: perl, if-statement

I use an ActivePerl script to take in CSV files and create XML files that I load into a database.  These are userid database entries, name, address, etc.  We've always used the home phone number field to generate an initial password (which we encourage the users to change immediately!).  The proliferation of cellphones means I have a bunch of people with no home phone, so I want to use the cell phone field when the home phone field is empty.

My input fields look like this:

```
#   0 Firstname
#   1 Lastname
#   2 VP (voicepart)
#   3 Address
#   4 City
#   5 State
#   6 Zip
#   7 Phone
#   8 Mobile
#   9 Email
```

Here's the Perl code I've worked up to create the password - the create_password subroutine is working when there's a value in field 7:

```
my $pass_word = '';
my $pass_word = create_password($fields[7]);
if (my $pass_word = '') { 
  print "Use the cell phone number \n";
  my $pass_word = create_password($fields[8]);
}
```

The "print" statement is to tell me what it thinks it's doing.

This looks to me like it should work, but the "if" statment never fires.  The Print statement doesn't print, and nobody with a value only in field 8 ever gets a password generated.  There must be something wrong with the way I'm testing the value of $pass_word but I can't see it.  Should I be testing the values of $fields[7] and $fields[8] instead of the variable value?  How DO you test a Perl variable for null value if this doesn't work?

Comment: Using the Perl debugger should have answered all the questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several problems in your code.

First of all, after you declared a variable using `my`, you don't need to add `my` before the variable when you use it;

Secondly, for this line:

```
if (my $pass_word = '')
```

I think you meant

```
if ($pass_word == '')
```

(`my` is removed, as talked in the first point)

`=` means assignment, which returns the value you assigned to `$pass_word`, which is `''` here, that's why this condition always return false.

But still, `==` is not correct here. In perl, we use `eq` to compare two strings. `==` is used to compare numbers.

So, remove all the `my` except the first one, and use `eq` to compare your strings.

Comment: Thank you - you are all correct, and it works now.  I did what Xu Ding suggested and it worked.  This is what happens when you pick up Perl again after a long lapse and have forgotten a basic :P  I greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 5):

You've got two major problems in here.

First one is your string equality test.  In Perl, strings are compared for equality using operator `eq` (as in `$string eq 'something'`). `=` is the assignment operator.

Second one is your (ab)use of `my`.  Each `my` declares a new variable that “hides” the previous one, so in effect you can never re-use its value, you're confronted to `undef` every time.

Replace `=` with `eq` in your `if` clause; remove all but the first uses of `my`, and you should be set!

Comment: Also, I think that `my` should be removed from all statements except the first.

Comment: `use strict` and `use warnings` would have complained loudly about each of these issues, if you have any interest in avoiding them in the future.

Comment: `use warnings` is enough, but good point nonetheless; I had no idea it could warn for these!

Answer (score 2):

`my` declares a new variable which  hides the variable with the same name in the surrounding scope. Remove the excessive use of `my`.